# Removing duplicates in pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, duplicates

I am struggling with one code that I am trying to write. I have a simplified dataframe of this type:

```
 ID  RecordingType Date        Sleep
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  30
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  40
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  50
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  60
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  70
 1   MinsAsleep    19/01/2022  100
```

The function is supposed to sum all the 'Sleep' values for the rows, where ID, RecordingType and Date are exactly the same, save it in the last row and delete all the rest. So, the result should be:

```
 ID  RecordingType Date        Sleep
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  250
 1   MinsAsleep    19/01/2022  100
```

The dataframe is much more complicated than that, so the part of code I have so far is handling this particular case:

```
temp_physdata = # dataframe I inserted above 
temp_physdata = temp_physdata.sort_values(by=['ID', 'RecordingType', 'Date','Sleep'], ascending=True).reset_index().drop(columns=["index"])
temp_physdata["ToRemove"] = False
dict_temp_physdata = temp_physdata.to_dict("records")

outputcolnames = {'MinsAsleep':'Sleep'}
    

for i in range(temp_physdata.shape[0]-1):
        
        curr_recording_type = dict_temp_physdata[i]["RecordingType"]
        next_recording_type = dict_temp_physdata[i+1]["RecordingType"]
        
        # Check if current and next row have the same ID and RecordingType and Date
        
        if (dict_temp_physdata[i]["ID"] == dict_temp_physdata[i+1]["ID"] and curr_recording_type == next_recording_type and dict_temp_physdata[i]["Date"] == dict_temp_physdata[i+1]["Date"]):

            # Check if current row is MinsAsleep recording
            
            if curr_recording_type == 'MinsAsleep':
                
                # Check if the next row is the last row with the same ID, RecordingType, and Date values
                
                if i+1 == temp_physdata.shape[0]-1 or (dict_temp_physdata[i+1]["ID"] != dict_temp_physdata[i+2]["ID"] or 
                                              next_recording_type != dict_temp_physdata[i+2]["RecordingType"] or 
                                              dict_temp_physdata[i+1]["Date"] != dict_temp_physdata[i+2]["Date"]):
                    
                    temp_physdata.at[i,"ToRemove"] = True
                    
                    # Update the last row with the sum of all the MinsAsleep Recording values
                    temp_physdata.at[i+1, outputcolnames[next_recording_type]] += dict_temp_physdata[i][outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]]
                    
                    # Mark all the other rows to be removed
                    
                     for j in range(i, temp_physdata.shape[0]-1):
                        
                         if dict_temp_physdata[j]["ID"] == dict_temp_physdata[i]["ID"] and curr_recording_type == dict_temp_physdata[j]["RecordingType"] and dict_temp_physdata[i]["Date"] == dict_temp_physdata[j]["Date"]:
                            
                             temp_physdata.at[j, "ToRemove"] = True
                          
            else:
            
                temp_physdata.at[i,"ToRemove"] = True
                temp_physdata.at[i+1,outputcolnames[next_recording_type]] = max(dict_temp_physdata[i][outputcolnames[curr_recording_type]], dict_temp_physdata[i+1][outputcolnames[next_recording_type]])

temp_physdata = temp_physdata[temp_physdata["ToRemove"] == False].reset_index().drop(columns=["index"])
```

Somehow, the result that I seem to be getting is something like that:

```
 ID  RecordingType Date        Sleep
 1   MinsAsleep    17/01/2022  220
 1   MinsAsleep    19/01/2022  100
```

So, it seems to be adding up all rows except of one row but deleting it as well.. I know I overcomplicated the code and it looks pretty ugly, but I am still learning, so don't laugh, please :D

I really don't understand why it doesn't work in this case. Particularly, it seems to work with 3 consecutive rows like that but not with 4 rows.

Answer (score 2):

This will just do:

```
df.groupby(["ID", "RecordingType", "Date"]).sum().reset_index()

   ID RecordingType        Date  Sleep
0   1    MinsAsleep  17/01/2022    250
1   1    MinsAsleep  19/01/2022    100
```

I think you had a calculation error where the total `Sleep` value should be 250 (instead of 220) for `Date` `17/01/2022`.

Comment: I can't really use the groupby method (I tried) because I have the next loop there that goes through the rest of the columns and recording types and it doesn't find the column names after I use the groupby method.. Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: yes, the 220 Value was for an example of a wrong result - corrected, thanks!

Comment: Then is it possible to separate each piece of work and combine the final results together? It probably doesn't make sense to write your own loop for this kind of tasks as it's nicely handled by pandas methods. So if you have other processes relying on the original df, I suggest you process them separately and join results afterwards so that you keep all the code and logic clean. It's just not a good idea and practice to have such a gigantic for loop for something you can easily accomplished using 1 line of code.